# Calcular a diferença de minutos entre dois campos input time

Tags: php, html5, formulário, datetime

Qual a melhor forma de calcular a diferença de **minutos** entre dois campos `input time` com PHP?

Exemplo de dois campos `input`:

```
<label for="Cseg3">Horário 1:</label>
<input type="time" id="Cseg3" name="Tsegs">
<label for="Cseg4">Horário 2:</label>
<input type="time" id="Cseg4" name="Tsegss">
```

Uma tentativa com [Datetime::dif](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) que não deu certo:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$val1 = $_POST ["Tsegs"];
$val2 = $_POST ["Tsegss"];

$datetime1 = new DateTime($val1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($val2);


$intervalo = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $intervalo;

?>
```

Inspecionando pelo navegador aparece o erro: localhost/caminho do arquivo php: 500 (Internal Server Error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Resolvido.**

O problema estava no formato da impressão. O correto, para campos time, é:

```
echo $intervalo->format('%H, %i');
```

Assim ele vai retornar diferença em horas e em minutos. Este é o código que funcionou pra mim:

```
<?php

$val1 = $_POST ["Tsegs"];
$val2 = $_POST ["Tsegss"];

$datetime1 = new DateTime($val1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($val2);

$intervalo = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

echo $intervalo->format('%H, %i');

?>
```

Esta é uma saída para a entrada 07:02 no primeiro campo e 12:20 no outro:

> 05, 18

Então, para encontrar apenas em minutos (como preciso), é só multiplicar a primeira saída por 60 e pronto.