# Como incluir propriedade do dateInterval dentro de uma variável

Tags: php, variáveis, dateinterval

Depois de conseguir a diferença de tempo entre dois campos `input time` (vide [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58899/calcular-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-minutos-entre-dois-campos-input-time)), não sei agora como faço para colocar estes valores dentro de variáveis, para assim poder utilizá-los em outras funções.

O `var_dump` da variável `$intervalo` (que guarda o `dateInterval`) é:

> object(DateInterval)#3 (15) { ["y"]=> int(0) ["m"]=> int(0) ["d"]=> int(0) **["h"]=> int(5) ["i"]=> int(18)** ["s"]=> int(0) ["weekday"]=> int(0) ["weekday_behavior"]=> int(0) ["first_last_day_of"]=> int(0) ["invert"]=> int(0) ["days"]=> int(0) ["special_type"]=> int(0) ["special_amount"]=> int(0) ["have_weekday_relative"]=> int(0) ["have_special_relative"]=> int(0) }

(em negrito acima estão os campos que interessam)

Então tentei algo como:

```
$hora = $intervalo[h];
```

ou

```
$hora = $intervalo["h"];
```

ou

```
$hora = $intervalo['h'];
```

Mas acho que o [h] não é um vetor... A pergunta é: como colocar a propriedade [h] em uma variável?

Pesquisei na página do manual, mas meu inglês não é lá estas coisas, então não resolveu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira palavra do var_dump mostra `object` então para acessar suas propriedades utiliza-se o operador seta `->`.

pode obter o valor da seguinte forma:

```
$hora = $intervalo->h;
```

ou ainda:

```
$hora = $intervalo->format('diferença de horas: %h');
```

[Lista dos parâmetros validos para format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: Perfeito, valeu mesmo!